# Is johnrengleman shadow plugin officially supported by gradle?

Tags: gradle

I was wondering if https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow
Is officially supported/certified by gradle ?

I want to use it in an organization which is particular about using certified / standardized software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "supported/certified by gradle". The Gradle team supports, well Gradle itself. Gradle it just like any Java library, it gets updated, but in a non-breaking fashion to not break plugin authors such as the Shadow plugin (unless it was a major upgrade with breaking changes). So, I guess you can say Gradle "supports" the plugin, but not really.

However, there are select plugins that Gradle uses as part of their smoke test suite. One of those smoke tests is [ShadowPluginSmokeTest](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/smoke-test/src/smokeTest/groovy/org/gradle/smoketests/ShadowPluginSmokeTest.groovy). The Shadow plugin is one of the most widely used plugins, so the Gradle team ensures that do not break the plugin unintentionally.

Certified/standardized software is more of organizational thing for the company you work for. It's up to enterprise architect or whatever to standardize *which* plugins to use in a given organization/company. Gradle does not offer anything of the sort